# hidden vs config line setting in candy-machine

Tags: nft, candy-machine-v3

what is the diffrences bettwen Config Line and Hidden settings in candymachine? and wich one is better?
i checked both of them in the candymachine docs but i didn't realize at the end of the day what is the core difference betwen them

Answer (score 1):

`Config settings` is a new feature in candy machine v3. Normally in config.json we used to keep all the long URLs and names and for minting 1000 items, they would take up a lot of space. [this example from docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/candy-machine-settings)

> Say you want to create a Candy Machine with the following
> characteristics:
>
> - It contains 1000 items.
> - The name of each item is “My NFT Project #X” where X is the item’s index starting from 1.
> - Each item’s JSON metadata has been uploaded to Arweave so their URIs start with “https://arweave.net/” and finish with a unique identifier
>   with a maximum length of 43 characters.
>
> In this example, without prefixes, we would end up with:
>
> - Name Length = 20. 16 characters for “My NFT Project #” and 4 characters for the highest number which is “1000”.
> - URI Length = 63. 20 characters for “https://arweave.net/” and 43 characters for the unique identifier.
>
> When inserting 1000 items, that’s a total of 83’000 characters that
> will be required just for storing items. However, if we use prefixes,
> we can significantly reduce the space needed to create our Candy
> Machine and, therefore, the cost of creating it on the blockchain.
>
> - Name Prefix = “My NFT Project #”
> - Name Length = 4
> - URI Prefix = “https://arweave.net/”
> - URI Length = 43
>
> With 1000 items, we now only need 47’000 characters to store our
> items.
>
> But that’s not it! You may use two special variables within your name
> or URI prefixes to reduce that size even further. These variables are:
>
> - $ID$: This will be replaced by the index of the item starting at 0.
> - $ID+1$: This will be replaced by the index of the item starting at 1.
>
> In our above example, we could leverage the $ID+1$ variable for the
> name prefix so we wouldn’t need to insert it on every item. We end up
> with the following Config Line Settings:
>
> - Name Prefix = “My NFT Project #$ID+1$”
> - Name Length = 0
> - URI Prefix = “https://arweave.net/”
> - URI Length = 43
>
> That’s right, our name length is now zero and we’ve reduced the
> characters needed down to 43’000 characters.

I think the benefit of `Hidden Settings`, creator creates but does not mint, buyer pays for mint. from the same docs:

> - First, the creator configures the name and the URI of every minted NFTs using the Hidden Settings. The URI usually points to a “teaser”
>   JSON metadata that makes it clear that a reveal is about to happen.
> - Then, buyers mint all these NFTs with the same URI and therefore the same “teaser” JSON metadata.
> - Finally, when all NFTs have been minted, the creator updates the URI of every single minted NFT to point to the real URI which is specific
>   to that NFT.